# Apple developper account - add non-dev member

Tags: ios

I have Apple dev account with:

```
Program - Apple Developer Program
Enrolled as - Organization
```

I want to add new people to my team so they can develop my app. However, they don't have a developer account. If I add them to users, they can log into their account, but don't see "Certificates, IDs & Profiles", so they cannot upload their "CSR". Instead, they see this:

[image]

I can add them via my account, but in this case, the name of the generated certificate is the same as my name and it creates a mess in Certificates.

How to correctly solve this? Do I have to add their CSR in my account and see the certificate with my name, or they need to have Dev account? Or is there any other way?

Comment: If they're seeing "purchase your membership" then it looks like they either do not  actually have access to your Team, or they are looking at their personal team and need to switch to your team (top right on Apple Developer)

Answer (score 1):

In order for users to see certificates you need to make sure to select "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" under "Additional Resources" for their permissions.

[image: apple developer account permissions]

Comment: I have selected this